# How can I fix a missing color in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I used homebrew to install emacs, replacing an older version of unknown provenance. At startup emacs complains `Unable to load color "dark cyan"` and some text in my elisp files is invisible: I see `(require '   )` instead of `(require 'foo)`.

There don't seem to be any references to dark cyan in my `.emacs.d/` files, so I think dark cyan must be part of the default scheme. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for a while, I found http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.macintosh.osx/6639

> Delete this file:
>
> ~/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr
>
> and dark cyan should come back.

So I quit emacs, moved that file to `~/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr-`, started emacs again... and it worked. I hope this fix is useful to someone else.